# git LFS tracked files are still big after git clone

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket

I use git LFS in my repo, but the files (tracked by git LFS) still have size.

I follow this [link](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#create-a-new-repo) and do these steps:

#### On gitlab/bitbucket

- create a new repo on gitlab(also tested on Bitbucket)

#### On local

- clone the repo on local PC
- check git LFS is installed : `git lfs install`
- create a big file `head -c 2M /dev/urandom > one.model`
- start to large file `git lfs track "*.model"`
- .gitattribute is ready
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "use lfs and upload one.model "`
- `git push -u origin master`

#### On gitlab/bitbucket

- one.model has label "LFS" on gitlab(Bitbucket website)

#### On local

- git clone the repo to another dir. Then go to repo-dir
- `ls -al` to check size, file's size is still big.

I also test it on gitlab/bitbucket, but get the same result
Do I miss any instruction or settings? 
Need your suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE`? You can do this by setting this in you environment directly:

```
GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone YOUR-REMOTE-REPO
```

or by setting it in config:

```
git config --global filter.lfs.smudge "git-lfs smudge --skip"
git clone YOUR-REMOTE-REPO
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello~magnusnn, `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone YOUR-REMOTE-REPO` is useful for me. But another is setting by `git config --global filter.lfs.smudge "git-lfs smudge --skip"` is nothing happened. BTW, the official torial doesn's say we have to add `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE`, why do I need to add this to get correct response? ths :)

Comment: @黃偉豪 Great to hear that the first option was useful for you. I do not now why the tutorial did not mention this..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the versions suggested by the tutorial? and have you properly installed git-lfs?

Maybe re-do the tutorial and try again?